# Is there a way to specify number of kmeans clusters to return in heatmaply

Tags: r, shiny, pheatmap, heatmaply

I would like to return a specific number of clusters for my interactive heatmap from `heatmaply` like I can do with `pheatmap` and the `kmeans_k =`  argument. Is there a way to do this with `heatmaply`?

If I have a large matrix and do not define the number of clusters to return with heatmaply, it takes too long to calculate the heatmap or I will get the error: 'vector memory exhausted(limit reached?)'.

```
library(pheatmap)
data(mtcars)
mat <- as.matrix(mtcars)

pheatmap(
  mtcars,
  border_color = "grey20",
  main = "",
  show_rownames = TRUE,
  show_colnames = TRUE,
  kmeans_k = 30,
  cluster_rows = F,
  cluster_cols = F
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `k_col`, and or `k_row` arguments.

You can see examples in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html), but just a simple example:

```
library("heatmaply")
heatmaply(mtcars, k_col = 2, k_row = 4)
```

Output:

[image]